# Adding a vertical rule (border) between two UIScrollViews

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I have two UIScrollView instances and I want to draw a vertical line between them (not 100% height, more like 80%).  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Core Graphics. Nest the two UIScrollViews inside another view and override the *drawRect* method on the parent. See Apple's [UIView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) for drawRect for more detail and the [Core Graphics Context Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html) for more information about drawing.

```
- (void) drawRect: (CGRect) rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Draw divider
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
        // Fill the background, this must happen if the view is not opaque.
            if (self.opaque)
            {
            [[UIColor whiteColor ] set];
            CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
            }

        [[UIColor grayColor] set];

        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1);

        CGContextBeginPath(context);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, rect.size.width * 0.5, 0.1 * rect.size.height);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.size.width * 0.5, 0.9 * rect.size.height);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    UIGraphicsPopContext(); 
}
```

---

*edit*

To address my oversight, there is no simple way that I know of to draw on top of subviews.

This behavior can be simulated using the same basic view hierarchy as above. Subclass UIView to create a completely transparent view that does not accept any touch events. Place the drawing code (I added a conditional for opacity in the code above) in the custom view and then insert an instance of the custom view at the front of the view hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I tried this but I don't see the line, I guess because the UIScrollView's are covering it.  Any idea how I might get around that?

Comment: I have updated my answer to address that oversight. I have tested the updated solution and can confirm that it will give you the desired behavior.

Comment: Hm, I'm having trouble getting the touch events to work properly.  Do you know how to make the transparent view pass the events to the scrollviews?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694529/allowing-interaction-with-a-uiview-under-another-uiview

Answer (score 1):

A vertical line between your views could also just be a thin, tall UIView (on top of the scroll views) with, say, a solid background color. This would mean you don't need to worry about custom drawing code. This also lets you lay it out in Interface Builder, use autosizing, etc.