# How can I pass a touch to a button underneath another view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uibutton

Pretty simple question, perhaps not so simple answer though:

I've got a clear view which needs to receive touches. *Underneath* this is a UIButton, which I also want to receive touches (for reasons I won't go into, it has to be underneath). In the case where the button is pressed, I don't want the clear view to receive the touches.

How can I do this?

**EDIT:**

Final Solution:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


    for (UIView * view in self.subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            CGPoint pointInButton = [view convertPoint:point fromView:self];
            if ([view pointInside:pointInButton withEvent:event]) {
                return view;
            }
        }
    }
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `userInteractionEnabled` to false for your clear view?

Comment: @aroth I need the clear view to receive touches too. Sorry should have been more specific in the question (which I'll edit now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the clear view a reference to the `UIButton`.  Override the clear view's `pointInside:withEvent:` method.  In your override, check whether the point is inside the button (by sending `pointInside:withEvent:` to the button).  If the point is in the button, return NO.  If the point is outside the button, `return [super pointInside:point withEvent:event]`.

Comment: Additional discussion here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694529/allowing-interaction-with-a-uiview-under-another-uiview

Comment: Thanks!! This is a great answer. I'm a bit stuck getting it working - any chance you'd be able to say why the code I'm using won't work (I've added it to my question)?

Comment: Aha... fixed with this line: CGPoint pointInButton = [view convertPoint:point fromView:self]; Thanks :)