# UITapGestureRecognizer with couple of views

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using :

```
       UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleViewClicked:)];
       [tmp addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
       [gestureRecognizer release];
```

to get notification when a view(`bigview` for our example) i clicked(I have a lot of view), and in the front there is a UIView (a blank one) the he is in the front of the view (there is a reason why this view is in the front before al the views).

there is now a problem to get notification when `tmp` is tapped because the `bigview` is in the front.

there is any solution for something like this?

EDIT

---

In the `bigview` i have `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeRight:)];
        [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
        [itemsView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
        [recognizer release];
```

and if i make userInteractionEnabled in the `bigview` to NO he don't get notification on swipe

Comment: Referring to your EDIT; "he don't get notification on swap" - did you mean to write "on swipe"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

A. Set `userInteractionEnabled` to NO on that big/blank view.

B. Implement `pointInside:withEvent:` on that big/blank view

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    // UIView will be "transparent" for touch events if we return NO
    return NO;
}
```

(as taken from [allowing-interaction-with-a-uiview-under-another-uiview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694529/allowing-interaction-with-a-uiview-under-another-uiview))

Comment: @MTA if I understand you correctly, then this "big" view should sometimes get touch-events and sometimes it should not, correct?

Comment: the big view always get UISwipeGestureRecognizer event but the views below him get UITapGestureRecognizer events