# I have custom UIButtons which are rotated 45 Degrees - how do I make it so that only the space within the actual shape is clickable?

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer

So my custom button looks like this:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.frame = self.layer.bounds

    let width = self.layer.frame.size.width
    let height = self.layer.frame.size.height

    let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path,nil,width/2, 0)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path,nil,width, height/2)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path,nil,width/2, height)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path,nil, 0, height/2)

    mask.path = path
    self.layer.mask = mask
}
```

I've added the button to a UIView in Storyboard, and subclassed it to this UIButton subclass. I set the background to blue in Storyboard.

**The result:**

[image: The result:]

The problem is then I click around the corners (the white space, as if the button was still being recognised as a square), it is still clickable. This is an issue because I want to add multiple shapes like this next to each other, so I don't want any of the Buttons to block each other out.
[image]

Comment: You cant. Because, you are not rotating the button frame,instead you are creating a custom image for your button. The red area is still considered as button frame. Try rotating the button,instead of writing the custom code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the [`pointInside`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/pointInside:withEvent:) function in your custom `UIButton` to control when a touch in your view's bounds should be considered a hit.

```
override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    let width = bounds.size.width
    let height = bounds.size.height

    // Make a UIBezierPath that contains your clickable area
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: width / 2, y: 0))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: width, y: height / 2))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: width / 2, y: height))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: height / 2))
    path.closePath()

    // Let a hit happen if the point touched is in the path
    return path.containsPoint(point)
}
```

See also

- [Allowing interaction with a UIView under another UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694529/allowing-interaction-with-a-uiview-under-another-uiview)

Answer (score 1):

How about adding UITapGestureRecognizer to the button view, get the coordinate of tap and convert the coordinates to parent view coordinate and compare if its in the twisted cube.

```
//sender being the UITapGestureRecognizer
let coordinate = containerView.convertPoint(sender.locationInView(ContainerView), toCoordinateFromView: containerView)
```